# Zodiac Table: Signs for birthdate?

Tags: java

So, for my intro programming class, we're making a zodiac table. It's void of a specific year and leap years, so that's nice. Moreover, we're doing input from a .txt file, so we don't have to worry about user input. Anyways, there's 4 columns and the Zodiac column needs to be defined by dates. So, Cancer is defined June 22 to July 22. I have the months and how long they are defined below:

```
case 1: if (dayNum >= 1 || dayNum <= 31)
                        dateWord = "January";
                    else 
                        validData = false;
                break;
            case 2: if (dayNum >= 1 || dayNum <= 28)
                        dateWord = "February";
                    else 
                        validData = false;
                    break;
            case 3: if (dayNum >= 1 || dayNum <= 31)
                        dateWord = "March";
                    else 
                        validData = false;
                    break;
            case 4: if (dayNum >= 1 || dayNum <= 30)
                        dateWord = "April";
                    else 
                        validData = false;
                    break;  
            case 5: if (dayNum >= 1 || dayNum <= 31)
                        dateWord = "May";
                    else 
                        validData = false;
                    break;
            case 6: if (dayNum >= 1 || dayNum <= 30)
                        dateWord = "June";
                    else 
                        validData = false;
                    break;
            case 7: if (dayNum >= 1 || dayNum <= 31)
                        dateWord = "July";
                    else 
                        validData = false;
                    break;
            case 8: if (dayNum >= 1 || dayNum <= 31)
                        dateWord = "August";
                    else 
                        validData = false;
                    break;
            case 9: if (dayNum >= 1 && dayNum <= 30)
                        dateWord = "September";
                    else 
                        validData = false;
                    break;
            case 10: if (dayNum >= 1 || dayNum <= 31)
                        dateWord = "October";
                    else 
                        validData = false;
                    break;  
            case 11: if (dayNum >= 1 || dayNum <= 30)
                        dateWord = "November";
                    else 
                        validData = false;
                    break;
            case 12: if (dayNum >= 1 || dayNum <= 31)
                        dateWord = "December";
                    else 
                        validData = false;
                    break;
            default: dateWord = "";
```

However, how would I list someone's zodiac sign? If the .txt file says my birthday is 6 (month column) 22 (date) column, how would I put their zodiac sign in the "Zodiac column?" Moreover, how would I list multiple signs if there is more than one birthday?

Comment: `more than one birthday` as in `someone was born more that once`?

Comment: What do you mean by "list", and "put their zodiac sign in the Zodiac column"? Are you outputting to a text file as well?

Comment: Please clarify what this program is supposed to produce.

Comment: Seems as if you were able to successfully extract a month string from the date.  What prevents you from using the same technique for the zodiac sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the month and the day from the table. Do this for all elements and put the zodiac sign into the table.

```
    int month = 2;
    int day = 23;
    ArrayList<String> zodiacSign = new ArrayList<String>();
    switch (month) {
    case 1:
        if (day < 20) {
            zodiacSign.add("Capricorn");
        } else {
            zodiacSign.add("Aquarius");
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (day < 18) {
            zodiacSign.add("Aquarius");
        } else {
            zodiacSign.add("Pisces");
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        if (day < 21) {
            zodiacSign.add("Pisces");
        } else {
            zodiacSign.add("Aries");
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        if (day < 20) {
            zodiacSign.add("Aries");
        } else {
            zodiacSign.add("Taurus");
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        if (day < 21) {
            zodiacSign.add("Taurus");
        } else {
            zodiacSign.add("Gemini");
        }
        break;
    case 6:
        if (day < 21) {
            zodiacSign.add("Gemini");
        } else {
            zodiacSign.add("Cancer");
        }
        break;
    case 7:
        if (day < 23) {
            zodiacSign.add("Cancer");
        } else {
            zodiacSign.add("Leo");
        }
        break;
    case 8:
        if (day < 23) {
            zodiacSign.add("Leo");
        } else {
            zodiacSign.add("Virgo");
        }
        break;
    case 9:
        if (day < 23) {
            zodiacSign.add("Virgo");
        } else {
            zodiacSign.add("Libra");
        }
        break;
    case 10:
        if (day < 23) {
            zodiacSign.add("Libra");
        } else {
            zodiacSign.add("Scorpio");
        }
        break;
    case 11:
        if (day < 22) {
            zodiacSign.add("Scorpio");
        } else {
            zodiacSign.add("Sagittarius");
        }
        break;
    case 12:
        if (day < 22) {
            zodiacSign.add("Sagittarius");
        } else {
            zodiacSign.add("Capricorn");
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Why is the return value an `Array`? Isn't only 1 return is possible?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a shorter version, couldn't find it anywhere on the web so decided to post here:

```
// Months are in ints - January is 1, February 2, etc.
public String getZodiac(int day, int month){
        switch(month){
            case 1:
                // if the day int is higher or equal to 20, return Aquarius,
                // otherwise Capricorn
                return day >= 20 ? "Aquarius" : "Capricorn";
            case 2:
                return day >= 19 ? "Pisces" : "Aquarius";
            case 3:
                return day >= 21 ? "Aries" : "Pisces";
            case 4:
                return day >= 20 ? "Taurus" : "Aries";
            case 5:
                return day >= 21 ? "Gemini" : "Taurus";
            case 6:
                return day >= 21 ? "Cancer" : "Gemini";
            case 7:
                return day >= 23 ? "Leo" : "Cancer";
            case 8:
                return day >= 23 ? "Virgo" : "Leo";
            case 9:
                return day >= 23 ? "Libra" : "Virgo";
            case 10:
                return day >= 23 ? "Scorpio" : "Libra";
            case 11:
                return day >= 22 ? "Sagittarius" : "Scorpio";
            case 12:
                return day >= 22 ? "Capricorn" : "Sagittarius";
            // A default option because the function needs a return value
            default:
                return "Error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this do exactly the same as the accepted answer, except that it's using in-line expressions instead of if blocks? The compiled code will e identical.

Comment: Ah, but humans are not compilers. I find it a lot more readable than the accepted version.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant version, with minimal repetition. It may not be good for learning the basics, but it should show you that, if your code looks like a lot of repetition is going on, then *there's a way to keep [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)*:

```
public static final TreeMap<Integer, String> SIGNS;
static {
    // map initialization is only performed once
    SIGNS = new TreeMap<>();
    SIGNS.put( 1_01, "Capricorn");
    SIGNS.put( 1_20, "Aquarius");
    SIGNS.put( 2_18, "Pisces");
    SIGNS.put( 3_21, "Aries");
    SIGNS.put( 4_20, "Taurus");
    SIGNS.put( 5_21, "Gemini");
    SIGNS.put( 6_21, "Cancer");
    SIGNS.put( 7_23, "Leo");
    SIGNS.put( 8_23, "Pisces");
    SIGNS.put( 9_23, "Libra");
    SIGNS.put(10_23, "Scorpio");
    SIGNS.put(11_22, "Sagittarius");
    SIGNS.put(12_22, "Capricorn");
}
public static String zodiacSign(int day, int month) {
    int key = month * 100 + day; // 10 feb = 210 = 2_10
    return SIGNS.floorEntry(key).getValue();
}
```

`TreeMaps` are Java's default sorted maps. The [floorKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry-K-) of a `TreeMap` returns

> a key-value mapping associated with the greatest key less than or equal to the given key

Oh, and this is a nice use-case of Java's support for any number of `_`s as part of a number.

Answer (score -1):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Month: ");
String m = in.nextLine();
int d;
String I = "Invalid";
String D = "Enter Date: ";
if (m.equals("Jan")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=19){
        System.out.println("Capricorn");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=20){
        System.out.println("Aquarius");
}
}
else if (m.equals("Feb")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=18){
        System.out.println("Aquarius");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=19){
        System.out.println("Pisces");
}
}
else if (m.equals("Mar")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=20){
        System.out.println("Pisces");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=21){
        System.out.println("Aries");
}
}
else if (m.equals("Apr")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=19){
        System.out.println("Aries");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=20){
        System.out.println("Taurus");
}
}
else if (m.equals("May")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=20){
        System.out.println("Taurus");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=21){
        System.out.println("Gemini");
}
}
else if (m.equals("Jun")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=20){
        System.out.println("Gemini");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=21){
        System.out.println("Cancer");
}
}
else if (m.equals("Jun")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=20){
        System.out.println("Gemini");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=21){
        System.out.println("Cancer");
}
}
else if (m.equals("Jul")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=22){
        System.out.println("Cancer");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=23){
        System.out.println("Leo");
}
}
else if (m.equals("Aug")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=22){
        System.out.println("Leo");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=23){
        System.out.println("Virgo");
}
}
else if (m.equals("Sep")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=22){
        System.out.println("Virgo");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=23){
        System.out.println("Libra");
}
}
else if (m.equals("Oct")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=22){
        System.out.println("Libra");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=23){
        System.out.println("Scorpio");
}
}
else if (m.equals("Nov")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=21){
        System.out.println("Scorpio");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=22){
        System.out.println("Sagittarius");
}
}
else if (m.equals("Dec")){
    System.out.print(D);
    d = in.nextInt();
        if (d<=0){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d<=21){
        System.out.println("Sagittarius");
}
        else if (d>=32){
        System.out.println(I);
}
        else if (d>=22){
        System.out.println("Capricorn");
}
}
else{
    System.out.println(I);
}
```

Comment: It is a good practice to explain shortly your answer and reuse question's code as much as possible.